# How to check whether advanced sharing setting was set or not after permission assignment?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing

Once a folder is shared with an user via advanced sharing by either checkmarking the below setting or unchecking it, then,

1. How can I later verify whether this option was checkmarked or not when permissions were assigned?
2. Where can I change this checkmark setting post permission assignment?

[image]